# How to enable --no-reset if appium server is started by AppiumServiceBuilder

Tags: java, appium

I have started Appium Server using AppiumServerBuilder

```
service = AppiumDriverLocalService
                    .buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                    .usingDriverExecutable(new File(nodeJsExecutable))
                    .withAppiumJS(new File(appiumJsExecutable))
                    .withIPAddress(appiumServerAddress)
                    .usingPort(appiumServerPort));
```

Now Appium Server gets started with default --full-reset capability, causing the app to reset every time on each run.
I need to set --no-reset for Appium Server so appium doesn't re install app everytime . How can I do that here?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set "noResetValue" appium capability which accepts boolean  value, true/false

when set to true , it prevents the app from re-installing each time, java example:

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();    
capabilities.setCapability("noResetValue","true");
```

Answer (score -1):

You will most likely need to set any such capabilities with the `.withCapabilities` method: http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/service/local/AppiumServiceBuilder.html#withCapabilities(org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities)

fullReset shouldn't be enabled by default in any case.